# Sorting array of dicts python?

Tags: python

With the following

**Code**

```
arr = [{"name":"joe", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"april", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"ryan", "hot dogs":8}]
```

How to in python sort the elements of the array such as the dicts are sorted by name?

```
arr = [{"name":"april", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"joe", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"ryan", "hotdogs":8}]
```

How to apply some function to sort the dicts in the array?

Comment: You have already 17 questions; it is high time you learn [how to format questions with markdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Is that your actual data structure, or a simplified example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
arr.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

Comment: `import operator`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following web page:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: Liked this answer as gave also some context.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.OrderedDict(april=5, joe=5, ryan=8)
OrderedDict([('april', 5), ('joe', 5), ('ryan', 8)]
```

---

Or per DSM's comment

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict([('april', 5), ('joe', 5), ('ryan', 8)])
OrderedDict([('april', 5), ('joe', 5), ('ryan', 8)])
```

Comment: While `OrderedDict` does preserve order, it can't be used with that call syntax.  For example, try `collections.OrderedDict(april=5, ryan=8, joe=5)`.  The problem is that the class gets passed an unordered dictionary of keyword arguments.

Comment: Lame. Thanks DSM, I didn't know that.